# Solving $2^x \cdot 5^y = 0,128$

Tags: exponential-function

$x,y \in \mathbb Z$

$2^x \cdot 5^y = 0,128$

$x+y = ?$

**My attempt:**

I know that

$$0,128 = \frac{128}{1000}$$

$$5^3 = 125$$

$$2^{-3} = \frac{1}{8}$$

---

**EDIT:**

$2^7 = 128$

Then we need to get

$0,128$

Comment: $2^{-3}=\frac{1}{8}$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout missed it, nice catch.

Comment: Does it help if I point out that $2^7=128$?

Comment: @MJD Now, got it better. The thing is to get $0,128$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $0.128=2^7\times 10^{-3}=2^4\times 5^{-3}$

Comment: How? I truly didn't get what you mean.

Comment: You can find $x$ and $y$ with that.

Comment: Yes, found that! However, I'd be grateful If you explain what you've done.

Comment: $2^x5^y=2^45^{-3}$. So, we have $2^x5^{y+3}=2^4$. As prime decomposition of an integer is unique, $x=4$ and $y+3=0$.

Comment: Hold on, why did you use $5^{-3}$ instead of $10^{-3}$?

Comment: $2^7\times 10^{-3}=2^7\times 2^{-3}\times 5^{-3}=2^4\times 5^{-3}$

Comment: I need prime decomposition to ensure the uniqueness. So we have to use $5$ instead of $10$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $128=2^7$, and $1000=10^3=(2\cdot 5)^3=2^3\cdot 5^3$. Therefore

$$0.128=\frac{128}{1000}=\frac{2^7}{2^3\cdot 5^3}$$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: For $1000$, we get $10^3$ hence $\frac{2^7}{10^3}$ and?

Comment: @Enzo, good! Now if you can write $10=2^x\cdot 5^y$ then $10^3=2^{3x}\cdot 5^{3y}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write 5 in terms of 10 and 2... so you can write the problem as:
$2^x \cdot (\frac{10}{2})^y=.128$

$2^{x-y} \cdot 10^y=.128$

Find $y$ first and then $x $